# Error: undefined reference to _imp_***

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors, mingw-w64

I am getting errors like `error: undefined reference to __imp__ZN12QApplicationC1ERiPPci'` and `error: undefined reference to __imp__ZN11QMainWindow11qt_metacastEPKc'` on project build. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding but nothing has worked.

I have seen many other posts about this error, but no fix methods have worked. I am new to Qt creator, so I am probably missing something big here, but I made a widget project. Here are the files:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setFixedSize(500,500);
    QPushButton myButton;
    myButton.setText("Hello world, this is a GUI app!!!");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**myWindow.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-03-11T19:52:19
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui


greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = myWindow
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
QT += sql #added because I found this to try and solve my problem, doesn't fix

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h
```

My Qt version 5.10.1, OS is Windows, compiler is MinGW 64.

Comment: How did you install Qt?

Comment: Link the object files or libraries defining the missing symbols.

Comment: How did you get this code .. its not showing the  `QBushButton`  object .. no  `ui` object

Comment: check your qt toolchain in tools->options->build&run. looks like it could not find qt libs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it myself, so here's what two things I messed around with:

1. Extending `QWidget` instead of `QMainWindow`

   (Pretty simple)
2. Checking my kits and using one with the correct version of MinGW  - not 64 or 32 bit, it was called something completely different but still had MinGW in the name ;)

Answer (score 0):

The fix is done by installing appropriate versions of the packages you are using. Some new code techniques can be a hard issue, so installing the right type of package can be hard but required sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this problem recently, and because it took me so long to find the solution I decided to add this answer here.

`undefinded reference to __imp_` in my case was an **indicator of lacking linking option** in my compile and link command.
To solve (with gcc compiler): add -L (to show a folder where the libraries to be linked are) and -l (in form -llibraryname).
For example, if project is located in C:/myproject, and there is a folder 'libs' inside. To link libusb0 and stcommdll, the line goes

```
gcc -LC:/myproject/libs -o executable_file.exe source_file.c -llibusb0 -lstcommdll
```

I assume there are equivalents for other compilers.